# Failed to sum variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script to sum amount that I get from ID's of html element, this is the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* var sum=0; */
    $('#checkAll').click(function(event) {  //on click 
        if(this.checked) { // check select status
            var i = 0;
            var sum = 0;
            $('.checkItem').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"
                sum = sum + parseInt($('#amount'+i).val());

                i++;
            });


        }else{
            $('.checkItem').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       

            });  
            sum=0;
            i=0;
        }
        $('#totalRecord').val(i);
        $('#totalAmount').val(sum);
        $('#totalAmountFake').val(ChangeToRupiah(sum));
    });
});
</script>

function ChangeToRupiah(angka){
    var rev     = parseInt(angka, 10).toString().split("").reverse().join("");
    var rev2    = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < rev.length; i++){
        rev2  += rev[i];
        if((i + 1) % 3 === 0 && i !== (rev.length - 1)){
            rev2 += ".";
        }
    }
    return rev2.split("").reverse().join("") + ",00";
}
```

But when i run it, i got this message in my result element :
[image]

I guess it's about limitation of javascript variable, but it's not, I use Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: And what does `ChangeToRupiah` do?

Comment: can you share the html sample as well

Comment: which field is wrong `totalAmount` or `totalAmountFake`

Comment: Try modifying your code as sum = parseInt(sum + parseInt($('#amount'+i).val()));

Comment: Your HTML need to understand your problem clearly.

Comment: post your `ChangeToRupiah` funtion

Comment: @ArunPJohny totalAmountFake is wrong

Comment: @Clouds i had add my ChangeToRupiah function

Comment: could u provide ur html..??